# How do I retrieve global contacts using the MS EWS Managed API?

Tags: c#, .net, exchangewebservices

The only question I could find on SO was from 3 years ago and is not working for me.
Context: I am creating a C# webservice that needs to retrieve all users from a company's directory. This particular method needs the name and email of each user so it can populate a few lists. I am using Microsoft Exchange Web Services Managed API 2.0 downloaded from: [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35371).

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the FindItems method with a paged search (so that you can limit the number of contacts returned in each message).

This topic has info about getting items (contacts are just items): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn535506(v=exchg.150).aspx#bk_getewsma. You'll want to create a property set to retrieve the name and email address from the ContactSchema.

And this topic has info about doing a paged search: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn592093(v=exchg.150).aspx.